# APScheduler Not picking jobs using mongodbjobstore and django

Tags: django, mongodb, apscheduler

Trying to schedule some jobs using `APScheduler`
Following is the apscheduler setup from `settings.py`

```
jobstores = {
  'default': MongoDBJobStore(client=dup_client),
}
executors = {
  'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
  'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}
job_defaults = {
'coalesce': False,
'max_instances': 3
}

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=TIME_ZONE)
scheduler.start()
```

Adding Job:

```
job_id = scheduler.add_job(job_1,'interval', seconds=10)
```

As mentioned in the documentation, `apscheduler` db and `jobs` collections are created. However jobs are not executed

I'm able to see in memory jobs getting executed. Problem is with persistent job stores.

Comment: Have you tried to enable debug logging (configuring the logging system with level=DEBUG)?

Comment: The problem was in server container file uwsgi.ini. uwsgi defaultly disables multiple thread support because of this scheduler was not created since it needs a separate thread.so just added thread-enabled = true in the uwsgi.ini file and its working now.

Comment: Now the scheduler is running,but after adding a job the scheduler is not picking the job.It needs application to be restarted. After application restarts then scheduler is picking executing the job.

Comment: I will repeat: have you tried to enable debug logging to see what's going on?